# Error Installing Oozie on Dataproc

Tags: hadoop, oozie, google-cloud-dataproc

I was first using a Dataproc initialization script provided by Google ([here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/oozie)) to install Oozie on a new cluster and noticed that I couldn't hit the UI or run jobs on the command line.

Diagnosing I went ahead and deleted the cluster then recreated a new one without the initialization script (none at all for the record). I then ran a sudo apt-get install oozie to get the following error:

```html
sayle_matthews@cluster-1-m:~$ sudo apt-get install oozie
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  bigtop-tomcat oozie-client
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bigtop-tomcat oozie oozie-client
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 306 MB of archives.
After this operation, 363 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://dataproc-bigtop-repo.storage.googleapis.com/v1.0/ dataproc/contrib bigtop-tomcat all 6.0.36-1 [5,376 k
B]
Get:2 http://dataproc-bigtop-repo.storage.googleapis.com/v1.0/ dataproc/contrib oozie-client all 4.2.0-1 [10.7 MB]
Get:3 http://dataproc-bigtop-repo.storage.googleapis.com/v1.0/ dataproc/contrib oozie all 4.2.0-1 [290 MB]        
Fetched 306 MB in 17s (17.6 MB/s)                                                                                 
Selecting previously unselected package bigtop-tomcat.
(Reading database ... 59410 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bigtop-tomcat_6.0.36-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking bigtop-tomcat (6.0.36-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package oozie-client.
Preparing to unpack .../oozie-client_4.2.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking oozie-client (4.2.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package oozie.
Preparing to unpack .../archives/oozie_4.2.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking oozie (4.2.0-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/oozie_4.2.0-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/oozie/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar', which is also in package oozie-client 4.2.0-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/oozie_4.2.0-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening? Or a possible workaround?

Comment: This was also mentioned in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/issues/44)

Comment: Yeah that was mine as well.

Comment: Ah cool! We're taking a look at this. :)

Comment: Thanks! Read commends there was able to force it to install, but appears to have been broken by an update.